# Возможен ли динамические шаблон без библиотек?

Tags: javascript

Скажите пожалуйста, возможно ли в моём случае в шаблоне использовать динамические значения(то есть такие, которые устанавливаются в js-коде)?

Для примера я написал скрипт, в котором получаю с сервера json и далее хотел бы вывести его на страницу при помощи цикла:

```
function constructValute(valuteArr) {
    console.log('constructValute start');

    var bodyEl = document.getElementById('body'),
            valuteArrLength = valuteArr.length;

    for(i = 0; i < valuteArrLength; i++) {
        var tpl = document.getElementById('item');
      var itemEl = document.createElement('div');
      var valueForDisplay = valuteArr[i].CharCode;
      itemEl.className = 'item';
      itemEl.innerHTML = tpl.innerHTML;
      bodyEl.appendChild(itemEl);
    }
};

function ajaxReq() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/daily_json.js');
    xhr.onload = function() {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
        var responseText = xhr.responseText;
        var responseTextParsed = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        var vauteList = responseTextParsed.Valute;

      //console.log('responseTextParsed is ', JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
      console.log('valute list is ', vauteList);

      var valuteArr = []
            i = 0;

        for(var prop in vauteList) {
            valuteArr[i] = vauteList[prop];
            ++i;              
            };

            console.log(valuteArr);

      constructValute(valuteArr);
    }
    else {
      console.log('Request failed.  Returned status of ' + xhr.status);
    }
    };
    xhr.send(); 
};

ajaxReq();
```

Сам шаблон находится в html:

```
<script id="item" type="text/template">
    <div class="item-inner">
        <div class="left">1</div>
        <div class="right">2</div>
    </div>
</script>
```

Проблема в том, что я не могу вставить в него значения valueForDisplay.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/z0tqa1yp/)

Comment: не вижу ни одного места, где ты пытаешься вставить в шаблон valueForDisplay

Comment: Потому что не знаю как это сделать. Но вообще хотел бы вставить сюда например, вместо единички: <div class="left">1</div>

Comment: обычно в шаблонах пишутся ключевые символы, которые потом заменяются регуляркой или string replace...... например в шаблоне будет что-то `<div class="left">{#var1}</div><div class="right">{#var2}</div>`, где шаблон вида `{#ИМЯ_ПЕРЕМЕННОЙ}` заменяется на переменную из кода

Comment: при этом переменные, которые передаются в шаблон могут быть в виде объекта `{var1: 'значение кастомное'; var2: 666}`. В итоге здесь ключ объекта будет как раз именем в шаблоне, вместо которого будет прилетать значение

Comment: Спасибо. Кажется, получилось